# Php live stream with custom media player

Tags: javascript, php, css, html, ftp

I am trying to play MP3 file. My script is placed on c:/ drive and MP3 file on d:/ drive. Google Chrome does not allow to load a local file into the browser. So, I have made d:/directory as FTP directory and tried to access a mp3 file through PHP by using FTP. 
I have done it successfully by the code given below...

```
<?php
$ftp_server = "server";
$ftp_server = ftp_connect($ftp_server);
$login = ftp_login($ftp_conn, 'username', 'password');
$filename = "ftp://username:password@server/directory/file.mp3";

header('Cache-Control: max-age=604800');
header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');
header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filename));
?>

<audio controls="controls"> 
   <source src="<?php readfile($filename);?>">
</audio>
```

Now, the problem is this due to `header('Content-type: audio/mpeg');` always a black screen appear on browser with chrome's builtin media player.

[image: Screenshot]

Whereas i want to know how i can play this MP3 file with custom media player.

Comment: it's better option to upload your audio on any cloud platform and use its public link inside src attribute. In this case, you don't need any PHP code, HTML5 is sufficient.

Comment: I cant use cloud platform. I need to run this script on local setup

Comment: readfile is blocking, your need to chunk the transfer, though if its a live stream the buffer wont end.

Comment: @LawrenceCherone can you explain a bit more please?